# Prevent button from being pressed twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am new to JavaScript and AngularJS. I have made a demo in that I made simple page navigation with modal, so when I click on a button I am going to another page. But my problem is when I click on that button twice it opens the same page twice. I have used timeout function but I don't know why it is not working on my demo, my code is as below.

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.foo = function() {
        if ($scope.filterflg !== "1" ) {
            $scope.filterflg = "1";
             $scope.disabled = true;


            gallery.pushPage("filter.html", {
                params: FkCategory
            });

            $timeout(function() {
                console.log("====timeout occured===");
                $scope.filterflg = "0";
                  $scope.disabled = false;
            }, 3000);
        }
    };
```

**HTML**

```
   <span class="toolbar-button--quiet navigation-bar__line-height" ng-click="foo();" ng-disabled="disabled"
                  style="border: none; padding: 0 5px 0 0;">
```

Comment: you can remove `click` eventListener from the button, maybe so: `this.setAttribute('ng-click', '');` in your `foo()`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you really shouldnt use jquery selectors in your controllers.

you should try the angular declarative way instead -

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.foo = function() {
   $scope.disabled = true;
    gallery.pushPage("filter.html", {params:$scope.filteid});

$timeout(function() {
    console.log("======time out occured======");
    $scope.disabled = false;
}, 0);
};
```

**HTML**

```
   <span class="toolbar-button--quiet navigation-bar__line-height" ng-click="foo();" ng-disabled="disabled"
                  style="border: none; padding: 0 5px 0 0;">
```

notice how i use the ng-disabled directive instead of jquery manipulations.

good luck.

Comment: Hello please see my edited question,Still it clicked twice and go to next page,Which i dont want..!!! :( please help

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` wouldn't modify the scope, because it's a native JavaScript function, which will run outside AngularJS context, and the the code which runs outside AngularJS context which is changing AngularJS `scope` will not reflect on the UI until you run the digest cycle manually.

So instead of using `setTimeout` you should use `$timeout` which will run a digest cycle for you.

Another reason behind the user is able to click button twice is you have `2000`ms (`2sec`) of timeout which is too much; reduce that as you want will make an immediate effect.

```
$timeout(function() {
    disabled = false;
}, 0);
```

Comment: Please see my edit,Still its not working,timeout occured but not achieved what i want.!

Comment: hello i have used this link but i really dont have idea how to apply it in my code.[Set timeout to a button click](http://jsfiddle.net/BvYwr/1/)

Comment: @FireCandy you need to inject `$timeout` dependency in your controller function..

Comment: injected but not achived my goal..:(

Comment: no any error,but my problem is when i am clicking to that button two time same page open and then when i return to previous page,A modal is displaying and never goes